# Need help to show an external site into a div with media in a relative path

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, curl

My goal is to create a website where you can insert an url into a textarea, open it and show it into a separate div in the same page.

The idea -> http://s10.postimg.org/pm4n1qms9/Cattura.png

I know that this question could be answered in the past (I read some other topics about it) but unfortunately no one helped me with the problem i'm going to explain.

THE PROBLEM: all the media in the page with a RELATIVE PATH give a 404 status. I know, this is normal but I would like to convert all the RELATIVE PATH into ABSOLUTE PATH or something else in order to show the media into the panel.

The problem -> http://s10.postimg.org/9mlzi6qqh/image.png

I'm not asking to do my job but i'm desperately looking for some hints or suggestions about that!

In case you need, here's the code

Client-side (javascript, Activates when the button below the url bar is pressed)

```
if (ValidURL($("#areaUrl").val())) {
$.ajax({
method: 'GET',
url: '...',
dataType: 'html',
data: {
 'requestedUrl': $("#areaUrl").val()
},
success: function (data) {
 console.log(data); 
 $('#mainContent').html(data);
},
error: function (xhr, status, error) {
 //something happens
 }
 });
 }
```

And here's the PHP server code

```
<?php

//the function I found to download the page with curl
function get_data($url) {
$ch = curl_init();
$timeout = 5;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
$data = utf8_decode(curl_exec($ch));
curl_close($ch);
return $data;
}

//answering the client...
$url = $_GET['urlRichiesto'];

$forTheClient = get_data($url);
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * ;'); 
header('Content-type: text/html; charset = UTF-8');

echo $forTheClient ;
```

A big THANK YOU to anyone who'll try to give me some hints!

Comment: Have you considered using an `iframe` instead of a `div`? This is precisely what they're for.

Comment: You're probebly looking for `file_get_contents()` to get the source code from the website. Next you need some regex to find relative paths like `src='images/some_image.png'` and insert the url in front of it. Probebly with `preg_replace()`. However, if media files are outside the docroot, you're in trouble and there's no way to fix that except downloading all media content to your own server and replacing source with that. Needles to say that you might get copyright issues with that.

Comment: I have to mention though that most websites will use CSS files for media content. In that case it gets a whole lot more complicated. It's still possible but the result will never be optimal.

Comment: mmm... and what if i wanted to EXCLUDE all the medias from the downloaded page ? Do you think it's possible?

Comment: What do you mean? You want to download an entire website inside a div but exclude all media? You do realise that what you're doing will cause so many issues that it's just not really viable do you? Like if the website contains any links and your users click on them, this will cause them to browse away from your website anyway. An `iframe` is probebly a way better solution.

Comment: However, I get the idea that you're developing this for users to be able to visit a website that's normally blocked for them. Therefor you want your server to "download" the website instead. An `iframe` would still trigger the block. Therefor it's probebly way better to setup a web-proxyserver.

Comment: Ok icecub, thanks a lot for your suggestion about the iframe. I'll look for it and i'll let you know.
By the way, this is for a uni project , and yes, probably i'm not realising very well what i'm doing because it's the first time I deal with javascript, ajax and similar so forgive me if i write obscenity :)

Comment: Perhaps you should take a look here: https://www.php-proxy.com/ It's easy to install and modify to what you want. The licence allows you to do pretty much whatever you want with it. I've tested it myself and it works perfectly including all media stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no direct way to crawl and show a web page as same as we see in the web browser.
Anyhow you have to convert relative to absolute paths (In html code as well as in JS & CSS).
But you have to be careful. If you insert the code directly to a div after crawling, the JS which is contained under that code will not get executed by the browser. So, the only way to do it is, through the code under an HTML iframe (throwing is diff from inserting) forcefully.

Comment: As suggested by you and Icecube (in the main post's comment), i'll try with an i-frame and i'll let you know. Thanks again!